# Lightswitch Stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, visual-studio-lightswitch

This is my stored procedure

```
Using connection = New SqlConnection
    '  Dim connectionStringName = Me.DataWorkspace.XtraReportsServiceData.Details.Name
    connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=WIN-BTU6KNHNEGR\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SapyLiveSystem;User ID=sa;Password=tytyty@21;Connection Timeout=3000000;"

    Dim procedure = "UpdateColorMatching"

    Using command = New SqlCommand(procedure, connection)
          command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
          connection.Open()
          command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using

End Using

'result = webservicesql.CallStoredProcuder
Log.log("Called after Stored Procedure")
```

It runs 100% on my development pc and if I call the stored procedure from a web service it runs 100% if I install it on the server and try and call that procedure from a webservice through light switch it wont run. If I call the webservice it runs 100% fine. If I run from lightswitch on development pc it works 100% fine buy not from server any help

Comment: Whilst I do not know the answer to your specific problems [this page](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/45/Tracing-Debugging-Your-LightSwitch-Application-In-Production.aspx) from Michael Washington's Lightswitch Website may help you better diagnose the problem.

Comment: Can you setup remote debugging on the server?  If you can you could break on the exception that is happening.  Another quick way to get some info would be to put a try/catch around this block and return the exception message to the client.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf8k2h6a.aspx